# how to get texures with models from 3ds max into blender

Tags: modeling

so I recently found out how to rip game models from a game, thing is for the texures to come with them I had to texture them in 3ds max. I use blender to animate so I was wondering if there was a way, if any to get the model from 3ds max **with the textures on it.** I tried doing it a few different ways but the texures were all messed up when i put them on the model. any ideas?

before you mark as a duplicate I know how to get the model in blender, I do not know how to make the textures correct on the model once it's in blender

Comment: I can get the model in there but the textures are not correct on the model

Comment: Kraven, it should be otherwise you are doing something wrong. What format did you export to?

Comment: .obj for the model and the textures are .jpg